# Pushing a Div Below Another

Tags: html, css

I have a div section (#section1) that I want to remain 100% height, but to expand if need be to fit other content. The width is 100%. I have another div below that one as you scroll down the page (#section2), same principle 100% height and width, with the height expanding as needed. My problem is, the second one won't push all the way down, due to the first div being absolute. Instead it is has the first section on top of it. Does anyone have any advice? I'm using Bootstrap 4 for this project.

```css
header {
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
html {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: none;
  height: 100%;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
#section1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#section2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#section2 p {
  background-color: inherit;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#section2 a {
  background-color: #2eb233;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}
#section2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: hsl(122, 79%, 38%);
}
```

```html
<!--Header-->
<header></header>

<!--Section 1-->
<div id="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 push-md-6">
        <div id="quote-section">
          <h1>What our customers <br> have to say...</h1>
          <div id="quote-box">
            <p><em>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore repellat eos quas, similique tempora at magni ab cumque blanditiis labore provident quae dolorem optio nobis vel debitis quasi, rem recusandae!"</em>
            </p>
            <p id="quote-location">(Location)</p>
          </div>

          <a class="call-to-action" href="#">Find A Location</a>
          <div id="border-section-off"></div>
          <a class="call-to-action" href="#">Order Our Home Study Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Section 2-->
<div id="section2">
  <h1>Who We Are...</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quaerat odit cumque assumenda voluptates ipsum nisi, aliquid consequuntur obcaecati commodi aperiam sequi officiis illo adipisci inventore, beatae, ex ab eveniet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quaerat odit cumque assumenda voluptates ipsum nisi, aliquid consequuntur obcaecati commodi aperiam sequi officiis illo adipisci inventore, beatae, ex ab eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Consequuntur iste suscipit deserunt ipsum officia, rerum. Aliquam distinctio, quia placeat praesentium, nesciunt fugiat, provident assumenda voluptates voluptate esse totam, nam vero!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Magni quia officia quasi voluptas animi ex delectus reiciendis, commodi, voluptatum nemo, ullam sequi saepe! Ut dicta quidem odit cupiditate. Reprehenderit, id.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero quibusdam in laborum nobis
    harum aspernatur, quidem repellat non nostrum, error dolore beatae saepe deserunt atque nemo repudiandae praesentium dolorem. Autem?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove `position:absolute` on your first section - it serves no purpose.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer did not meet your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need section 1 to be absolute, if you remove that attribute everything will work fine run this code below:

```css
header {
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
html {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: none;
  height: 100%;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
#section1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  //position: absolute;
}
#section2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#section2 p {
  background-color: inherit;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#section2 a {
  background-color: #2eb233;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
}
#section2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: hsl(122, 79%, 38%);
}
```

```html
<!--Header-->
<header></header>

<!--Section 1-->
<div id="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 push-md-6">
        <div id="quote-section">
          <h1>What our customers <br> have to say...</h1>
          <div id="quote-box">
            <p><em>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore repellat eos quas, similique tempora at magni ab cumque blanditiis labore provident quae dolorem optio nobis vel debitis quasi, rem recusandae!"</em>
            </p>
            <p id="quote-location">(Location)</p>
          </div>

          <a class="call-to-action" href="#">Find A Location</a>
          <div id="border-section-off"></div>
          <a class="call-to-action" href="#">Order Our Home Study Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Section 2-->
<div id="section2">
  <h1>Who We Are...</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quaerat odit cumque assumenda voluptates ipsum nisi, aliquid consequuntur obcaecati commodi aperiam sequi officiis illo adipisci inventore, beatae, ex ab eveniet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo quaerat odit cumque assumenda voluptates ipsum nisi, aliquid consequuntur obcaecati commodi aperiam sequi officiis illo adipisci inventore, beatae, ex ab eveniet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Consequuntur iste suscipit deserunt ipsum officia, rerum. Aliquam distinctio, quia placeat praesentium, nesciunt fugiat, provident assumenda voluptates voluptate esse totam, nam vero!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Magni quia officia quasi voluptas animi ex delectus reiciendis, commodi, voluptatum nemo, ullam sequi saepe! Ut dicta quidem odit cupiditate. Reprehenderit, id.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero quibusdam in laborum nobis
    harum aspernatur, quidem repellat non nostrum, error dolore beatae saepe deserunt atque nemo repudiandae praesentium dolorem. Autem?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using position absolute to make the first section go all the way to the top, with the header on top of it. Essentially what I'm looking to do is have the first section fill the browsers height all the way by default, and expand if need be. The second section, and some other sections I plan to add, will also fill the browsers height.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried this earlier, but I must've not been looking at it in same way. When I came back to it, I was able to find how to fix the unknown white space above it,  that is caused with removing the absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks Colton, also I would suggest you to look into bootstrap, it is a good framework and will make your things easy. [Bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, you could ditch position absolute and min-height from the sections and use:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Which would set the sections to 100% of the browser viewport's height.

It's a fairly recent addition though, so check http://caniuse.com/viewport-units/

Comment: I'm looking to support all of the major browsers, being Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera as well.

Comment: IE8 would be the only blocker then.